# Adding extra component in map iteration gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration

I am new to React. I have following Iteration where i am adding number of `<td>`

```
<tr key={rowIdx}>{
    Array.from({length: numberOfColumn}).map((_, colIdx) => (
       <EditableCell key={colIdx}/>
    ))

}</tr>
```

Now i want add one extra td which have remove button at the end of every tr.

[image]

But, it shows error at following place.

```
<tr key={rowIdx}>{
    Array.from({length: numberOfColumn}).map((_, colIdx) => (
      <EditableCell key={colIdx}/>
    ))


   //Error is here
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="X"/>
    </td>

}</tr>
```

I don't have idea how can i add extra TD. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the correct format

```
<tr key={rowIdx}>
    {Array.from({ length: numberOfColumn }).map((_, colIdx) => (
        <EditableCell key={colIdx} />
    ))}
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="X" />
    </td>
</tr>;
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. :)